# Titanium tableView refresh

Tags: sqlite, titanium, tableview, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

How do I add an event listener so that a table is updated when the window/tab is in focus? My Current code works for webViews but I am unsure as how to apply it to tableViews. `win.addEventListener('focus',function(e){webview.reload();});`

Answer (score 3):

create a method that reloads the data for the table and call `table.setData(_tableData)`

Comment: @Aaron Saunders: FYI, there's a [proposal on Stack Exchange's Area51 for an Appcelerator only SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40242/appcelerator). It'd be awesome to have you support the proposals!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your table, defined as:

```
var tableData = [{title: 'Elephants'}, {title: 'Donkeys'}, {title: 'Falcons'}]

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: tableData
})
win.add(tableView)
```

And an array called `newData` that has the new information you want to place in the table. Have you tried doing the following?

```
win.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    tableView.data = newData
})
```

Let me know if you need more information or if this doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: What I want is for an SQL statement to be reprocessed every time the window/tab is viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can perform in your current Code.

```
win.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    tableView.setData(newData); // this is always add update Array
});
```

for example

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var data = [
    {title:"Row 1"},
    {title:"Row 2"},
    {title:"Row 3"}
];

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: data
});

win.add(tableView);
win.open();
```

Try again this

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    var data = [
        {title:"Row 1"},
        {title:"Row 2"},
        {title:"Row 3"}
    ];

    var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        data: data
    });
data = [
        {title:"Row 1"},
        {title:"Row 2"},
        {title:"Row 3"},
    {title:"Row 4"},
    {title:"Row 5"},
    ];
win.addEventListener('focus',function(){
      tableView.setData(data);
});
win.add(tableView);
win.open();
```